# Angular 6 json object pipe not display data

Tags: html, json, angular, mongodb

I have an html file that is trying to display tasks for a project. The tasks are contained in an ref array inside the project schema that I get from MongoDB. When I try the code below:

```
<div class="card-body">
    {{project.taskName | json}}
</div>
```

It displays the entire task object like this

> [ { "project": [ "5bd973fe33bd3a09586c8eb2" ], "user": [], "_id": "5bd9776833bd3a09586c8eb3", "taskName": "Test task", "taskDescription": "This task is a test", "__v": 0 } ]

If I try {{project.task.taskName | json }} nothing gets displayed. How do I get the html to display the tasks name and description? Thanks!

**EDIT:** the json payload I receive

```
[
    {
        "team": [],
        "task": [
            {
                "project": [
                    "5bd973fe33bd3a09586c8eb2"
                ],
                "user": [],
                "_id": "5bd9776833bd3a09586c8eb3",
                "taskName": "Test task",
                "taskDescription": "This task is a test",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5bd973fe33bd3a09586c8eb2",
        "projectName": "Test project",
        "projectDescription": "This is a test project",
        "__v": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue comes from the fact that your payload (project) is an array.

This should work fine:
{{ project.taskName[0].taskName | json }}

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your help mate but still nothing is returned. Any other things I could try?

Comment: Oh wait you display project.taskName and it gives you the array ?
Then maybe {{ project. taskName[0].taskName | json }}
Maybe the payload structure could be improved. Would you have the related class ? It could help understand the model.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks so much for your help mate

Answer (score 1):

> The best would be to have a small `function` which gets only the desired properties like `taskName` and `taskDescription`.

```
 getCustomProjects() {
    return this.project.map(p => {
      return {
        name: p.taskName,
        taskDescription: p.taskDescription
      }
    });
  }
```

html

```
<div class="card-body">
    {{ getCustomProjects() | json}}
</div>
```

Note : You can call `getCustomProjects` and construct new array if in ts instead of html.

Working demo is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2chhvd

Answer (score 0):

You should not use |json with dot operator, if you need to print the whole object, use

```
<div class="card-body">
    {{project | json}}
</div>
```

if you need taskName

```
<div class="card-body">
    {{project.taskName}}
</div>
```

**EDIT**

You need to access using index since it is an array

```
   <div class="card-body">
        {{project[0].taskName}}
   </div>
```

Comment: It still returns nothing when I try it

Comment: It should work, the marked answer and mine has no difference

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe object using JSON `{{project.task | json }}`.
In your case  **project.task.taskName** is not a object it is a string. So there is no need of pipe JSON. You can simply use 
`{{ project.taskName }}`

Comment: Thanks for payload. Here task is not a object, it is an array, so you have to iterate over it using *ngFor

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me

```
array

abc = [
    {
      'team': [''],
      'task': [
        {
          'project': [
            '5bd973fe33bd3a09586c8eb2'
          ],
          'user': [''],
          '_id': '5bd9776833bd3a09586c8eb3',
          'taskName': 'Test task',
          'taskDescription': 'This task is a test',
          '__v': 0
        }
      ],
      '_id': '5bd973fe33bd3a09586c8eb2',
      'projectName': 'Test project',
      'projectDescription': 'This is a test project',
      '__v': 1
    }
    ];
```

html

```
<div class=="card-body">
  {{abc[0].task[0].taskName}}
</div>
```